# Cakephp - how check row is null?

Tags: cakephp, database-connection

I want to set flash message if there's not fullfilled row "surname" in database. How can I check if row surname is null ?

I tried to make something like this:

```
if(!isset(['User']['surname'])
```

or

```
if($user(['User']['surname']) === NULL
```

it obviously doesnt work

Comment: Checking with isset on a defined item can go wrong, especially when a string is returned here. In most cases `if(!empty(...))` suffices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check it like.

```
<?php 

if(!isset($user['User']['surname']) || empty($user['User']['surename'])){
 // your code goes here
}
```

Comment: this will evaluate to true even when the database field is not present or been removed from the array some other way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(empty($user['User']['surname'])) { 
    // your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check like this

> if(isset($user['surname']) || empty($user['surname'])){
>       $this->Session->setFlash('No Data.');
>   }